# Get VirtualBox server booting status

Tags: virtualbox

I have a database server that is started from a VirtualBox VM. I can start my development only after the dataBase VM boots up. How can I check whether the dataBase server has been booted up successfully. I am well aware of the command VBoxManage showvminfo  
but it shows the State as 'running' itself even when the VM is still booting up.

Is there a way to check the booting status?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect not, as even the Vagrant project seems to use a constantly-retrying SSH connection with a large timeout to determine if the machine is ready.

Comment: I was hoping there'd be another way to check this status.. :(